# Switching to tty from lightdm displays glitched characters

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, tty

I've had this problem with two virtual machines, where trying to log into my machine from lightdm just returns me to the login screen. The logical step would be to switch to tty and try to fix it, but this is what is displayed instead:

[image]

The tty itself seems to be working, since I can run commands, and I can witch between tty.

In these machines, I installed a lamp package from the UbuntuServer16.04 iso, as well as the package xubuntu-desktop with the flag --no-install-recommends.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to replace `witch` with `switch` so that English translators can accurately parse the question.